# Ecto config in dependencies

Tags: configuration, dependencies, elixir, ecto, elixir-mix

I have two `mix` projects P1 and P2.

P1 depends on ecto and provides a genserver interface. It is also added as a dependency in P2 only to have access to some client functions. So P2 does not try to start P1. It is started independently.

The problem is that P2 cannot be compiled. `mix compile` says that the the adapter configuration for `P1.Repo` is missing.

I do not want to include any repo configuration for P1 inside P2. Is there any way to use functionality provided by P1's modules inside P2 under these circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

This is Ecto specific, but you can provide compile-time config when defining a module as a repo.

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo do
  use Ecto.Repo, otp_app: :my_app,
                 adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres
end
```

You can then add runtime config in the repo's `init/2` callback.

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo do
  use Ecto.Repo, otp_app: :my_app,
                 adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres

  def init(_type, config) do
    new_config = Keyword.put(config, :url, System.get_env("DATABASE_URL"))

    {:ok, new_config}
  end
end
```

A more generic solution would be to provide application config as part of `mix.exs`'s `:env` option. I believe this is runtime only though (someone please correct me if I'm wrong).

Here's what `mix help compile.app` provides on this.

> :env - default values for the application environment. The application
>       environment is one of the most common ways to configure applications. See
>       the Application module for mechanisms to read and write to the application
>       environment.

Here's an example of `application/0` in `mix.exs` using `:env`.

```
def application do
  [extra_applications: [:logger, :crypto],
   env: [key: :value],
   registered: [MyServer]]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If P1 is dependency of P2, P2 is responsible for configuration and nothing can change that, but you have couple of other options:

- use [umbrella project](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/dependencies-and-umbrella-apps.html#umbrella-projects) The umbrella project can have its own config with P1.Repo. This way you keep P1 and P2 configs cleaner.
- additionally you can tear out meaningful chunk from P1 that is used by P2 and move it to P3. Both P1 and P2 depend on P3.